# Delete multiple list items from workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a loop in a workflow that is inserting new items into a list. Before the loop runs, I need to clear out any existing values in the list that match the criteria of the data being inserted (for instance, CategoryID).

The only option I see is to delete a single item in the workflow.

How can I either delete multiple items (maybe a REST call) or get a list of items that match my criteria and loop through them?

Comment: Is this SP 2010 or 2013 workflow? Please mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no direct looping out of the box in SharePoint Designer. You can work with tricks like those describer here:

[SharePoint Looping Workflow - How to: Loop through and process all items in a list](http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-looping-workflow-how-to-loop.html)
 or
 [SharePoint Designer Workflows 2 – Developing a For Each Loop for Workflows](http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/01/sharepoint-designer-workflows-2.html)